# Type mismatch (Error 13) with a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a simple bisection code to pinpoint the root of an equation. To do this, I input the formula into Excel's VBA and ran it to find it has a mismatch error. The error pops up at the line "MyFunc ="

I have checked the syntax and it appears correct. Both the values called and the parentheses contain the same variable.

```
Function MyFunc(T)
Dim a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3, 
a4, b4, c4, d4, n1, n2, n3, n4 As Double
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("E4").Select
a1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("F4").Select
b1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("G4").Select
c1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("H4").Select
d1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("E5").Select
a2 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("F5").Select
b2 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("G5").Select
c2 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("H5").Select
d2 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("E6").Select
a3 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("F6").Select
b3 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("G6").Select
c3 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("H6").Select
d3 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("E7").Select
a4 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("F7").Select
b4 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("G7").Select
c4 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("H7").Select
d4 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("C5").Select
n1 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("C6").Select
n2 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("C7").Select
n3 = ActiveCell.Value
Range("C8").Select
n4 = ActiveCell.Value


MyFunc = -2635500 + (((n1 * (a1 * (T - 298.15)) + 
(1 / 2 * b1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + 
(1 / 4 * d1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4))) + (n2 * (a2 * (T - 298.15)) + 
(1 / 2 * b2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c2(T - 298.15) ^ 3) + 
(1 / 4 * d2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n3 * (a3 * (T - 298.15)) + 
(1 / 2 * b3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + 
(1 / 4 * d3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n4 * (a4 * (T - 298.15)) + 
(1 / 2 * b4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + 
(1 / 4 * d4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)))
End Function
```

It's just a formula to store a value, T, to be used in bisection code to find the root of the equation below.

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4088852). You should be assigning values directly, although it looks like you should *really* be using an array here give that you have contiguous cells. Also, only `n4` is a `Double` - if you don't explicitly type all of them they default to `Variant`. The type mismatch could be anywhere - you're not validating any of the input. Set a breakpoint on the `MyFunc =` line, and check the values to see which one is not the correct type. Also consider splitting the formula so it doesn't overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
Function MyFunc(T)

Dim a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3, _
a4, b4, c4, d4, n1, n2, n3, n4 As Double

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    a1 = Range("E4").Value
    b1 = Range("F4").Value
    c1 = Range("G4").Value
    d1 = Range("H4").Value
    a2 = Range("E5").Value
    b2 = Range("F5").Value
    c2 = Range("G5").Value
    d2 = Range("H5").Value
    a3 = Range("E6").Value
    b3 = Range("F6").Value
    c3 = Range("G6").Value
    d3 = Range("H6").Value
    a4 = Range("E7").Value
    b4 = Range("F7").Value
    c4 = Range("G7").Value
    d4 = Range("H7").Value
    n1 = Range("C5").Value
    n2 = Range("C6").Value
    n3 = Range("C7").Value
    n4 = Range("C8").Value

    MyFunc = -2635500 + (((n1 * (a1 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4))) + (n2 * (a2 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c2(T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n3 * (a3 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n4 * (a4 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)))
End Function
```

Your `Dim` statement assigns only n4 as a double. All other variables are variants. If you define the parameters as part of your function definition you can input the values more flexible to your function:

```
Public Function MyFunc2(a1 As Double, b1 As Double, c1 As Double, d1 As Double, _
                        a2 As Double, b2 As Double, c2 As Double, d2 As Double, _
                        a3 As Double, b3 As Double, c3 As Double, d3 As Double, _
                        a4 As Double, b4 As Double, c4 As Double, d4 As Double, _
                        n1 As Double, n2 As Double, n3 As Double, n4 As Double, _
                        T As Double)

    MyFunc2 = -2635500 + (((n1 * (a1 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d1 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4))) + (n2 * (a2 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c2(T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d2 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n3 * (a3 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d3 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)) + (n4 * (a4 * (T - 298.15)) + _
        (1 / 2 * b4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 2) + (1 / 3 * c4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 3) + _
        (1 / 4 * d4 * (T - 298.15) ^ 4)))
End Function
```

In your worksheet you define the formula: `=myFunc2(E4, F4, G4, ...)`